# Chat search facility not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

When I go into the chat lobby and use the search facility, no results are returned, even for strings I know are present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: mine no wurk eithar

Comment: however, http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=easter+eggs&user=&room=198 still works

Comment: @Loong  -It's weird. When you repeat the search, it gets different results each time

Comment: @Valorum That's _status-by-design_ for the easter eggs.

Comment: Related: [Chat search is returning no results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279613/271002)

Comment: It's still broken

Comment: @Loong WOW. I never knew this thing existed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#talk) is a hint.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hmm, [scifi doesn't seem to have any other Easter eggs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [tag:status-not-completed]

Comment: @WadCheber Damn, spoke too soon. Bug me again tomorrow. Or bug Adam - he's the guy to sort this out; I'm just repeating what he's said on main meta.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [Already bugged him](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9696/chat-search-facility-not-working?noredirect=1#comment26859_9698)

Comment: @WadCheber [meta-tag:status-completed-from-a-certain-point-of-view]

Comment: @WadCheber - Sorta fixed = sorta broken.

Comment: @Valorum Half full = half empty. No, seriously, it should be fixed now. Can you still see any issues?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

### It should be working again now.

See [Chat search is returning no results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279613/chat-search-is-returning-no-results/279620#279620) on main meta, where a dev has just posted that a fix is underway. At least for me, the chat search facility is back to normal.

Comment: I've just tested it. It's still not working properly.

Comment: Results seem patchy for me.

Comment: @Valorum Hmm. The answer on main meta suggested the fix might take a while to complete. Let's wait a bit and see if it's fully resolved in the next hour or two.

Comment: Re-indexing is complete now. Let me know if you see issues.

Comment: @Adam - It's only showing up to April 2015. I'll leave it a while longer, but I thought you'd want to know.

Comment: @Adam - Still only producing results up to mid-2015.

Comment: Hrm. That's weird. Will look.

Comment: @Adam - I don't know if this helps, but the range of dates produced had been slowly expanding as of a couple of hours ago, but it stalled out at some point since then.

Comment: @WadCheber Good to know, thanks. I don't know too much about how chat indexing works. This may be a side-effect of the reindexing earlier? I don't think it should be, but hey. Fingers crossed that I don't have to do anything. ;) It's not throwing exceptions like earlier, so whatever is going on looks to be a new problem.

Comment: This should be totally resolved now per Nick Craver.